# Black Screen with Cursor after installing CUDA 7.5 on 14.04

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia, graphics, cuda

I have been setting up a deep learning machine using a GTX 980 Ti and have been attempting to install CUDA on my system.

I installed both the [352.41](http://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/90279/en-us) display driver and `cuda_7.5.18_linux.run` from [here](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads). I got both up and running just fine, the system booted without any issues. However, when I came back to start compiling the CUDA samples I was met with the following warnings on some of the package installs:

> WARNING: libGLU.so not found
>
> WARNING: libX11.so not found

I followed the instructions on the [getting started with CUDA on linux](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-getting-started-guide-for-linux/#download-nvidia-driver-and-cuda-software) page and tried to install `libGLU.so` with the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install libglu1-mesa libxi-dev libxmu-dev
```

This didn't work so I then tried to install the mesa implementation using the following:

```
sudo apt-get install libglapi-mesa && sudo apt-get install libosmesa6
```

This worked, I could now compile all of the CUDA samples. However, I'm thinking that this is where the error is originating from. I've included everything else I did before poweroff for reference

After this I started building the necessary dependencies for [Caffe](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/installation.html). I installed `BLAS` and started installing dependencies for [OpenCV](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_install/linux_install.html) using the folling commands:

**BLAS**

```
sudo apt-get install libblas-dev
sudo apt-get install libblas-doc
```

**OpenCV Dependencies**

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
sudo apt-get install cmake git libgtk2.0-dev pkg-config libavcodec-dev libavformat-dev libswscale-dev
sudo apt-get install python-dev python-numpy libtbb2 libtbb-dev libjpeg-dev libpng-dev libtiff-dev libjasper-dev libdc1394-22-dev
```

At this point I had to step aside and do something else. So I powered off and came back the next day to the system booting into a black screen with a cursor (driver failure).

I went into text mode and purged my nvidia drivers and reinstalled. I was then greeted by the error of not being able to log in past the the login screen (flashing black screen, then brought back to the login prompt).

At this point I'm thinking of putting up a fresh ubuntu install, but I'd still like to try and figure out what went wrong before I throw in the towel.

Comment: Just an update, I ended up putting up a fresh install, avoiding building the `libGLU.so` dependencies and have had no issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, after many more installs of ubuntu and re-configurations I found that the error was being caused by me installing both the current nvidia graphics driver as well as the accelerated graphics driver packaged with the cuda toolkit. They were conflicting and causing the system to never load into tty7.

Comment: My installation is from *deb (net install), and `cuda-drivers` depends on `nvidia-352` and other `nvidia-352-*` packages, so perhaps they both need to be installed..

Comment: @maxb I have 352 installed, however in the .run installation of CUDA 7.5 I did it asks if you'd like to install an accelerated graphics driver. This has nothing to do with CUDA and is simply a stripped down driver to run parallel. So my errors were being caused by the accelerated driver and 352 competing